# Nested indexing in PowerBi Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

This is my data

| credit | EMP Number | credit _ Quarter | Quarter_Index | month_Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| €300. | 1104282 | Q2 Y1 | 2 | 7 |
| €525. | 1104282 | Q4 Y1 | 4 | 7 |
| €375. | 1104282 | Q1 Y2 | 5 | 7 |
| €375. | 1104282 | Q3 Y1 | 3 | 7 |
| €0. | 1104282 | Q1 Y1 | 1 | 7 |
| €300. | 1104282 | Q2 Y1 | 2 | 4 |
| €375. | 1104282 | Q4 Y1 | 4 | 4 |
| €375. | 1104282 | Q3 Y1 | 3 | 4 |
| €0. | 1104282 | Q1 Y1 | 1 | 4 |

I want to find the sum of credit for each distinct EMP Number in last 4 quarters now the problem here is i have repeated credit quarter like Q1 Y1 is twice here I only want to consider the most recent one by referring to month_index

for example
Credit Quarter Q1Y1 and Month_index 4 and Credit Quarter Q1Y1 and Month_index 7 I only want to consider the Q1Y1 value with highest month index in this case i wan to consider Credit Quarter Q1Y1 and Month_index 7.

I want the sum of credit to be €1575 by only considering these four records

| credit | EMP Number | credit _ Quarter | Quarter_Index | month_Index |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| €300. | 1104282 | Q2 Y1 | 2 | 7 | Include |
| €525. | 1104282 | Q4 Y1 | 4 | 7 | Include |
| €375. | 1104282 | Q1 Y2 | 5 | 7 | Include |
| €375. | 1104282 | Q3 Y1 | 3 | 7 | Include |
| €0. | 1104282 | Q1 Y1 | 1 | 7 | Exclude |
| €300. | 1104282 | Q2 Y1 | 2 | 4 | Exclude |
| €375. | 1104282 | Q4 Y1 | 4 | 4 | Exclude |
| €375. | 1104282 | Q3 Y1 | 3 | 4 | Exclude |
| €0. | 1104282 | Q1 Y1 | 1 | 4 | Exclude |

and this should happen for each emp number.

Could you guys please help me on this. Thanks

I tried this dax but didnt work

```
credit_sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        TOPN(
            4,
            VALUES('osds'[Quarter_Index]),
            CALCULATE(
                MAX('osds'[Month_Index]),
                FILTER(
                    ALL('osds'Quarter_Index]),
                    'osds'[Quarter_Index] <> MIN('osds'[Quarter_Index])
                )
            )
        ),
        CALCULATE(
            sum('osds'[credit])
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Please help by pasting the first data table as [markdown table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) instead of as an image.

Comment: Thanks, I have added it as a markdown table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
credit_sum = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT(osds[EMP  Number]),
    SUMX(
      CALCULATETABLE(TOPN(4, DISTINCT('osds'[Quarter_Index]), [Quarter_Index], DESC)),
      CALCULATE(MIN('osds'[credit]), CALCULATETABLE(TOPN(1, 'osds', [month_Index], DESC)))
    )
  )
```

With comments for explaination:

```
credit_sum = 
  SUMX(

    // for each EMP  Number - needed for totals
    DISTINCT(osds[EMP  Number]),

    SUMX(

      // get top four quarters
      //   Note CALCULATETABLE required to keep context from above
      CALCULATETABLE(TOPN(4, DISTINCT('osds'[Quarter_Index]), [Quarter_Index], DESC)),

      // then for each get credit from the highest month index
      //   Note MIN('osds'[credit]) used incase TOPN returns multiple rows
      //   Note CALCULATETABLE required to keep context from above
      CALCULATE(MIN('osds'[credit]), CALCULATETABLE(TOPN(1, 'osds', [month_Index], DESC)))

    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the explanation! Helps a lot. Can you explain `Note CALCULATETABLE required to keep context from above`? I couldn't quite get it.

Comment: `CALCULATETABLE` is needed so that the `TOPN` is done in context of parent calculation (row context) - for example `TOPN(4..)` in context of each `[EMP  Number]`. Without `CALCULATEDTABLE` it would return `TOPN(4..)` of the whole table.